# Why does intellij idea say that function is not used

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        My<H> m = new My<>(new H());
        m.get();
    }
}

interface iface {
    void run();
}
class H implements iface {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}

class My<F extends H & iface> {
    private F o;
    My(F o) {
        this.o = o;
    }
    void get() {
        o.run();
    }
}
```

In the Idea Intelligence program version 2019.2, I get a light bulb with a notification that the run function is not used in the iface interface. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ is saying this because nothing would break even if `run` were removed.  The only time you call `run` is `o.run()`, but `o` is definitely a subclass of `H` (according to the generic constraint), so it definitely has a `run` method declared, no matter `iface` declares a `run` method or not.

A way to remove this warning is to make the generic constraint `F extends iface`.

Comment: If you remove run and keep the Override annotation you will still get error.

Comment: @SujayMohan Well, I didn't mean it _that literally_. Maybe a better word is "refactored out"?